# Odoo V10 - Get a value when store = False

Tags: python, odoo

Here is a python code:

```
@api.multi
def convert_bin_dec(self):
    for record in self:
        print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
        # on récupère les valeur booleenne pour chaque enregistrement
        value_monday = record.half_pension_monday
        value_tuesday = record.half_pension_tuesday
        value_thursday = record.half_pension_thursday
        value_friday = record.half_pension_friday
        # On assigne une valeur si c'est True ou False à chaque jours
        if value_monday:
            monday_decimal = 1
        else:
            monday_decimal = 0

        if value_tuesday:
            tuesday_decimal = 2
        else:
            tuesday_decimal = 0

        if value_thursday:
            thursday_decimal = 8
        else:
            thursday_decimal = 0

        if value_friday:
            friday_decimal = 16
        else:
            friday_decimal = 0
        # On fait le total
        total_decimal = monday_decimal + tuesday_decimal + thursday_decimal + friday_decimal
```

...

Here are the fields in the same class:

```
half_pension_monday = fields.Boolean(string='Monday', copy=False, store=False)
half_pension_tuesday = fields.Boolean(string='Tuesday', copy=False, store=False)
half_pension_wednesday = fields.Boolean(string='Wednesday', copy=False, readonly="1", store=False)
half_pension_thursday = fields.Boolean(string='Thursday', copy=False, store=False)
half_pension_friday = fields.Boolean(string='Friday', copy=False, store=False)
```

In my view, although I check some days of the week, my variable "total_decimal" gives a value of zero, knowing that my fields have a store = False option.

I would like to know if it is possible to work around this problem apart saving the fields in the database (store = True)?

My goal is not to record the days of the week in a database.

Thank you in advance !

**EDIT : 
New function :**

```
# Fonction qui permet de convertir en binaire
    @api.onchange('half_pension')
    @api.multi
    def convert_bin_dec(self):
        # for record in self:
        for record in self:
            if record.half_pension:
                print "Je suis dans la fonction convert"
                # on récupère les valeur booleenne pour chaque enregistrement
                value_monday = record.half_pension_monday
                value_tuesday = record.half_pension_tuesday
                value_thursday = record.half_pension_thursday
                value_friday = record.half_pension_friday
                # On assigne une valeur si c'est True ou False à chaque jours
                if value_monday:
                    monday_decimal = 1
                else:
                    monday_decimal = 0

                if value_tuesday:
                    tuesday_decimal = 2
                else:
                    tuesday_decimal = 0

                if value_thursday:
                    thursday_decimal = 8
                else:
                    thursday_decimal = 0

                if value_friday:
                    friday_decimal = 16
                else:
                    friday_decimal = 0
                # On fait le total
                total_decimal = monday_decimal + tuesday_decimal + 
                                thursday_decimal + friday_decimal
                # record.half_pension_days_value = total_decimal
                # self.half_pension_days_value = total_decimal
                print total_decimal
```

**half_pension_days_value** is the fields with ***store=True***

Comment: Usually fields with `store=False` are calculated fields or fields you retrieve from somewhere other than the database (a.k.a. a REST API). Can you obtain all your fields value by any of these means?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The only way to recover these fields is by the action of booleans in Odoo's view

Comment: If you need those fields in the view  and you can't calculate them or retrieve them in any other way then you should save them in your database. Otherwise you're trusting the registry to keep your model cached long enough for you to access those values.

Comment: with decorator, it's not possible ? with onchange for example ?

Comment: `@onchange` will alter those values but as soon as the orm cache decides to dispose of the cached values you will lose them.

Comment: my goal is to keep track with a field that will be stored in the database. This field will retrieve the value of the variable "total_decimal". 
I just want to put the values ​​in the cache while waiting for the full processing of the function

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to know if it is possible to work around this problem apart saving the fields in the database (store = True)?

The short answer is: no.

The purpose of not stored fields is for computed fields whose value depends on the context. If their value is not context dependant, even for those you should store them, for performance reasons.